# I have a button inside a View, Inside a Scroll View, Inside a View. I cant click it

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

It's not registering the click, what's wrong?

There's a button inside a view, inside a scroll view, inside a view.  And it's displaying properly

So the Container View contains the Scroll View, and the Scroll View contains the Content View, and the ContentView contains the button.

Comment: Check if the views and scrollview "clipToBounds" properties are set to YES and check if the button is really inside the view bounds.

Comment: The button is inside the view bounds.  Setting the contentView clipToBounds to yes made it all disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I had to align center x / y the button to the superview now I can click.  YAY

Comment: Please mark this as an answer when you get the chance. It appears the solution was to position the button inside the bounds of its parent view.

Comment: It appeared to be in the bounds though because it was displayed where i set the margins..  Why is that?

Comment: If you have the Size Classes property enabled on the Storyboard, it is possible that the button's position was changed to be relative to the available screen space. In this situation, the button will not appear where you placed it on the Interface Builder unless you set up Auto Layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing the "User Interaction Enabled" property on some of those layers.**  In Interface Builder, it's a checkbox in the "View" section.  The Views, ScrollView, and Button will all have them.

[image]

Given how complex your situation is (and the fact that some layers, like the ScrollView, DO need to respond to touches), I can't say off the top of my head which configuration you need, but I've had similar problems and that was the solution.

Basically, my app thought I was touching the View rather than the button inside it, so turning off "User Interaction Enabled" for the View made the app realize that I was trying to touch the button.

Comment: @TimNuwin I'm saying, the solution may be to UNCHECK some of them, probably the two Views.  That way, the app knows you aren't trying to tap on the View itself, you're trying to tap on the button within it.

Comment: @TimNuwin Ha!  Just understood the confusion.  :P  By "check that property" I meant "*check out* that property" or "look into that property."  Not literally "check the box."  Sorry about that.  Hahaha

Comment: This answer is not accurate enough. It should be added as a comment rather than an answer.